# Connected geometric thickness two

Tags: co.combinatorics, graph-theory, discrete-geometry

A graph $G = (V,E)$ has geometric thickness two if there exists an embedding $\varphi: V \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2$ and a decomposition $E = E_1\cup E_2$ such that $G_1 = (V,E_1)$ and $G_2 = (V,E_2)$ are both plane with this embedding. Here by “plane” I mean that all edges are drawn as **straight line segments** which do not intersect.

For instance, it is easy to see that $K_5$ has thickness two.

I am looking for a connected graph $G$ with geometric thickness two such that for any valid embedding and any valid decomposition, both graphs $G_1$ and $G_2$ are connected.

Comment: Do you assume that all edges are represented by segments?

Comment: From some doodling, for $K_5$ there exists an embedding and a decomposition such that $G_1$ and $G_2$ are plane and connected. I don't think any decomposition is doable, for example it implies that for every vertex any decomposition needs to asign at least one adjacent edge to each part of the decomposition.

Comment: @quarague, by exhaustion no subgraph of $K_6$ serves as an answer.

Comment: Did you check whether the Sulanke's nine-color Earth–Moon map on the wikipedia page for graph thickness https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thickness_(graph_theory) is such an example?

Comment: - Yes, the term plane, means representing edges by segments. Good question.
- Clearly, you can find a decomposition of the edges that make the drawing connected. That is easy. The difficult part is to find a graph such that every embedding and decomposition has this property.

Comment: @quarague: the wikipedia page considers thickness and not geometric thickness of a graph. I do not think that the graph on the Wikipedia page has geometric thickness 2. I did not check the graph carefully though. Thanks for the pointer.

Comment: Unfortunately, it seems that I found the disconnected drawings for all graphs form my answer. So I deleted it and returned the bounty.

Comment: @quarague Sulanke's nine-color Earth–Moon map has $11$ vertices and $50$ edges, whereas any $11$-vertex graph of geometric thickness two has at most $48$ vertices, see the paper ``[On representations of some thickness-two graphs](https://people.clas.ufl.edu/avince/files/Thickness2.pdf)'' (Computational Geometry **13** (1999) 161–171) by Joan P. Hutchinson, Thomas Shermer, and Andrew Vince.

Comment: Do you know of any graph that has a unique geometric thickness two embedding? I feel like that could be a good start for a construction.

Comment: This condition can be seen to be equivalent to requiring that all components of $G_1, G_2$ have at least one edge (i.e. have no isolated points) for all valid decompositions, but I also can't find an example where this seemingly weaker condition seems to hold.

Comment: @domotorp The closest result which I know is Fig. 3 from the paper *[Thickness  and  colorability  of  geometric  graphs](https://daneshyari.com/en/article/415167)* (Computational Geometry **56** (2016) 1-18) by Stephane Durocher, Ellen Gethner, Debajyoti Mondal, where are shown "all the three combinatorially different conﬁgurations of nine points that support geometric thickness-two drawings of" $K_9$ without an edge.

Comment: If you are happy with an infinite example, I think $\mathbb{Z}^2$ with edges of slopes $(1,0),(0,1),(1,2),(1,3),(2,1),(3,1)$ does the trick.

Answer (score 6):

*Disclaimer*. This answer does not solve the problem. I decided it is probably more useful to keep my answer here, but please know it is just a long comment.

*Notation*. For a graph $(V,E)$, we call $e=|E|, v=|V|$.

---

In a planar graph, we have a maximum number of edges: $e\leq 3v-6$ if $v\geq 3$. Thus, for a graph of thickness $2$, we have the trivial upper bound
$$ e\leq 6v-12. $$

**Proposition 1.** *Let $(V,E)$ be a graph with thickness** *$2$ and such that $e\in\{6v-14,6v-13,6v-12\}$. Then for any decomposition $E=E_1\cup E_2$ such that the graphs $(V,E_1),(V,E_2)$ are planar, the two are also connected.*

***Remark**. As you can check from the proof, the proposition is true for both the geometric thickness and the “normal” thickness.

> *Proof*. To see that, assume you decompose $E=E_1\cup E_2$. Since $(V,E_i)$ must be planar graphs (and $v\geq 5$), we have
> $$|E_i|\leq 3|V|-6$$
> Since $|E|\ge 6|V|-14$ and $|E_1|+|E_2|=|E|$, it follows that
> $$ |E_i|\geq 3|V|-8. $$
> Now, I claim that the two subgraphs cannot be disconnected. In fact, to any disconnected planar graph with $v\geq 4$ you can add at least three edges while still keeping it planar (the main reason is that any face of a planar graph has at least three vertices). But if you add three edges to $E_i$ you make it exceed the maximum number of edges for a planar graph, so both $(V,E_1)$ and $(V,E_2)$ must be connected.

Note that such a graph would require at least $v\geq 11$, since for $6v-14\leq {n\choose 2}\iff n\geq 11 \text{ or } n\leq 2$.

---

**Edit 1**. Thanks to the nice remark of Alex Ravsky, we know that such a graph cannot exist with **geometric thickness** $2$, although graphs with “normal” thickness $2$ exist with $e=6v-12$ (or at least, [I know of such an example for $v=12$](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/455655/sharp-upper-bound-of-the-number-of-edges-for-graphs-of-thickness-two)). In particular we can say something about a graph like the one in Proposition 1.

**Lemma 2.** *Assume $(V,E)$ is a graph with $e=6v-12-c$, $c\in\mathbb N$. Then, in any representation of the graph in $\mathbb R^2$ **where edges are not necessarily straight lines** and such that $E$ can be written as a disjoint union of planarly embedded graphs, the number of edges $e’$ that do not intersect with any other edge is at most $c$.*

> *Proof*. As from the comment of Alex Ravsky, call $E’$ the set of edges that do not cross other edges, and call $E’’$ the set of remaining edges. Then write $E’’=E’’_1\cup E’’_2$ such that $E_i’’$ are planarly embedded. Then, $E’\cup E’’_i$ are also planarly embedded, in particular
> $$ |E’’_i|+|E’|\leq 3|V|-6. $$
> This leads to
> $$ |E|+|E’|\leq 6|V|-12, $$
> which proves the Proposition.

**Corollary 3.** *Any graph with **geometric** thickness $2$ satisfies $e\leq 6v-15$.*

> *Proof*. The convex hull of the graph cannot have edges that intersect with other edges, and it is made of at least $3$ edges.

Comment: If you take from the above cited Wikipedia page about graph thickness, the graph there described related to "Sulanke's nine-color Earth–Moon map", i.e. the join of a 6-vertex complete graph and 5-vertex cycle graph, which has thickness two, then add two edges to the 5-vertex cycle graph, by which the thickness doesn't change, you have $v=11$ and $e = 6v-14=52$ as desired.

Comment: But we need to check if the geometric thickness of that graph is also two.

Comment: I think it is extremely unclear whether you can do that without increasing the thickness.

Comment: I think the main idea of the answer cannot provide a required example. Indeed, suppose for a contradiction that $E'$ is the set of the edges of the convex hull of the vertex set of the graph and $E''$ is the set of the remaining edges of the graph. Note that $|E'|\ge 3$. Let $E''=E''_1\cup E''_2$ be decomposition of $E''$ into the edges of the respective graphs. Then $|E'|+|E''_i|\le 3v-6$ for each $i\in\{1,2\}$. Thus $$|E|\le |E'|+|E''_1|+|E''_2|\le 2(3v-6)-3=6v-15<6v-14=|E|,$$ a contradiction.

Comment: @AlexRavsky your idea is very interesting, but I am not fully convinced that your argument works. In particular, $E’\cup E’’_i$ is not necessarily planar as it might seem. Sure, $E’$ is the outer perimeter in some representation of the graph, and $E_i’’$ is planar, so has no self-intersections in some **other** representation of the graph. But if the representations do not coincide, the union could be not planar. For instance, take $K_5$, and take any representation where it has 3 edges as perimeter. If you remove those three edges, the remaining graph has self-intersections, but it is planar.

Comment: And if you start from the beginning with a representation in which $E_1’’$ and $E_2’’$ are planar, first of all I am not sure it always exists (that is something I don’t know). But even if it did, it is not guaranteed that the convex hull of the graph has at least three vertices: you could have intersections of edges on the perimeter of the graph, which makes not even clear how to define the convex hull…

Comment: @LorenzoPompili The common vertex embedding is fixed both for $G_1$ and $G_2$, see the beginning of the question.

Comment: @AlexRavsky right, I missed that, thank you. Ok, now I see that your argument works. I am so silly that I did not read the requirement of the edges being straight lines in the question. I edited the answer to sum up the discussion.

Comment: For each natural $n\ge 4$, any $n$-vertex graph of geometric thickness two has at most $6n-18$ edges, see the details in 
Tony Huynh's [answer](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/454425/minimum-number-of-common-edges-of-triangulations/455679#455679)
to the other recent OP bounty question and my comment to it. Also it the referenced paper is posed Question 1, whether for $n>4$ there exists a graph of geometric thickness two on $n$ vertices with either $6n-18$ or $6n-19$ edges.

Comment: The bounty and best regards.

Comment: Well, I started a new one x) My answer is not worth 100 rep

Answer (score 3):

I tried to find a required example, but failed (I share my findings below). Nevertheless, it seems rather strange to me if there is no such example, so I hope that it can be constructed.

A natural idea is to look for rather dense graphs of geometric thickness two. Density of the latter graphs was studied in [HSV].
There is shown that for each natural $n\ge 4$, any $n$-vertex graph of geometric thickness two has at most $6n−18$ edges.
On the other hand, according to Theorem 1 from [DGM], for each $n\ge 9$ there exists an $n$-vertex graph of geometric thickness two with $6n−19$ edges.

We start from complete graphs. The graph $K_9$ has thickness three [BHK, T] and the biggest order of a complete graph of geometric thickness two is eight, see Theorem 2.1 from [DEH] or [HSV, 2.1]. But the graph $K_8$ has the disconnected drawing, see Fig. 2 from [HSV]. Moreover, as far as I can see at Fig. 3 from [DGM], even the complete graph $K_9$ minus one edge has the disconnected drawing.

The complete bipartite graphs of geometric thickness two were less promising candidates, because they are rather sparse. Indeed, it is easy to construct the disconnected drawing of the graph $K_{4,k}$ for any natural $k$ and the disconnected drawing of the graph $K_{6,6}$ is shown at Figure 2 from [DEH].

*References*

[BHK]
J. Battle, F. Harary, Y. Kodama,
*Every planar graph with nine points has a nonplanar complement*,
Bull. Amer. Math. Soc. **68** (1962) 569–571.

[Bei] L.W. Beineke
*[Biplanar Graphs: A Survey](https://core.ac.uk/download/pdf/82563356.pdf)*,
Computers Math.Applic. **34**:11 (1997) 1-8.

[DEH] Michael B. Dillencourt, David Eppstein, Daniel S. Hirschberg,
*[Geometric Thickness of Complete Graphs](https://jgaa.info/getPaper?id=23)*,
Journal of Graph Algorithms and Applications **4**:3 (2000) 5-17.

[DGM] Stephane Durocher, Ellen Gethner, Debajyoti Mondal,
*[Thickness  and  colorability  of  geometric  graphs](https://daneshyari.com/en/article/415167)*,
Computational Geometry **56** (2016) 1-18.

[E] David Eppstein,
*[Separating Thickness from Geometric Thickness](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0204252)*,
arXiv, 2003.

[HSV] Joan P. Hutchinson, Thomas Shermer, Andrew Vince,
*[On representations of some thickness-two graphs](https://people.clas.ufl.edu/avince/files/Thickness2.pdf)*,
Computational Geometry **13** (1999) 161–171.

[Tut]
W.T. Tutte,
*On the non-biplanar character of the complete $9$-graph*,
Canad. Math. Bull. **6** (1963) 319–330.